# Multiple WebViews in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, webview

I have tried to use WebView as a source for wrapping an ad in a react native application.

After Googling a ton on "multiple WebViews react native" without a good answer, I wonder if it is possible to use multiple WebViews in one screen?

I am not successful on loading the content for more than one of the WebViews I include in a screen on the iOS Simulator. In the phone I sometimes can load two. But it is inconsistent upon which of the WebViews that is loaded.

Since the app does not crash or report any errors when using multiple WebViews I guess it is possible in some way?

To be noted: I am loading the same url with different parameters in every webview. For example I can have urls like: url.com?param=1, and url.com?param=two.